# Create different list from value in column 2 based on value in column 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with 2 columns. I want to add values from column 2 to a three differents lists depending to the values in the other column

this is exemple of the table :'

`df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z'], 'col2':['owl', 'fox', 'horse', 'dog', 'lion', 'bird']})`

Expected output :

`list_x = ['owl', 'dog']`
`list_z = ['bird', 'horse']`
`list_y = ['fox', 'lion']`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

list_x = df.loc[df['col1'] == 'x', 'col2'].values
list_y = df.loc[df['col1'] == 'y', 'col2'].values
list_z = np.flip(df.loc[df['col1'] == 'z', 'col2'].values)

print('list_x', list_x, 'list_y', list_y, 'list_z', list_z)
```

Output

```
list_x ['owl' 'dog'] list_y ['fox' 'lion'] list_z ['bird' 'horse']
```

This uses explicit [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) indexing. Indexes in square brackets on the left (in this case it is a Boolean mask, which is obtained for example: df['col1'] == 'x'), on the right is the column name. To get an array from a series, I applied values. Applied np.flip to flip the array. What was ['horse' 'bird'] became ['bird' 'horse'].